# .mat tree-like structure settting up pre-processing parameters

Tags: matlab

I have a further question about opening up a .mat file.  It is a "tree like structure" which specifies the pre-processing steps for image analysis and is a SPM5 Batch-File.  Is there an easier way to view this file than by moving through it section by section?  I'm trying to update this for re-analysis.

For example, by typing...

jobs{2}.spatial{2}.coreg{1}.estimate

I can see what parameters are set for estimation.  However, is there a way to get an output of the entire tree like structure?  Or is there an easier way to view the final levels of the tree like structure?

I'm hoping that this makes sense, sorry again, I am a new user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know Matlab does not have any built-in way of displaying the full content of recursive structs. However, if you know your programming abc, writing a recursive function for displaying it will not be a huge task. Simply start at the top, loop through all fields using `fieldnames(...)`, determine for each field if it is a leave or a struct and possibly decent and repeat.

Regards